# Extrinsic camera matrix if translation performs before rotation

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, linear-algebra, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

An extrinsic camera matrix (E) is formed by a Rotation (R) matrix (3x3) and a Translation (t) vector (3x1).

```
E = [R|t]
```

If I have a 3D point `A = [x, y, z]'`, the transformation from 3D to camera coordinate will be `EA`. That is, on the x-axis `v_xrt = r_11 * x + r_12 * y + r_13 * z + t_1`. This transformation is correct if Rotation is performed before Translation. The complete transformation for all axes is,

```
|r_11 r_12 r_13 t_1|   |x|
|r_21 r_22 r_23 t_2| x |y|
|r_31 r_32 r_33 t_3|   |z|
                       |1|
```

This extrinsic matrix is well-known in the literature.

If Translation is done before Rotation. On the x-axis, the transformation is `v_xtr = r_11 * (x + t_1) + r_12 * (y + t_2) + r_13 * (z + t_3)` (Note that `v_xrt != v_xtr`). The complete transformation for all axes is,

```
|r_11 r_12 r_13|   |x + t_1|
|r_21 r_22 r_23| x |y + t_2|
|r_31 r_32 r_33|   |z + t_1|
```

How can I compute an extrinsic camera matrix in this case (Translation Before Rotation)?

Comment: **R** (**x** + **t**)  = **R** **x** + **t'**.  You want this **t'** ? If so, it will be **t'** = **R** **t** .

Comment: So... in this case, how to finish...?
(for example, in other site I know, question owner should post as answer and choose it himself. But how in here? nothing to do?)